# How to add a user without using the 'useradd' or 'adduser' commands in RHEL6.3?

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel

I want to add a user in a RHEL6.3 OS without using `useradd` or `adduser` command. 
I know that I have to edit in 4 files i.e passwd, group, shadow and gshadow.

But please tell me what exactly I have to edit?

Comment: These files are in `/etc/`; but I believe you might be wrong avoiding the commands.

Comment: Depending on what you trying to achieve, but one of the option - look at the `pam_module`

Answer (score 2):

Still not recommend to create a new user manually, but you can follow below steps to do it. For example, you need create a new user user3185704

**(before edit, backup /etc/passwd, group, shadow)**

1. edit /etc/passwd, add below line:

   user3185704:x:100:1000:user3185704,,:/home/user3185704:/bin/bash
2. if group (gid=1000) is exist, no need update /etc/group , otherwise, add a new group line in /etc/group.
3. add below line in /etc/shadow

   user3185704::::::::
4. create home directory

mkdir /home/user3185704

chown 100:1000 /home/user3185704

1. set password

   password /home/user3185704
2. manually test you can login

   su - user3185704